# STL random_sample replace with a decreasing probability

Tags: c++, stl, random

The STL `random_sample` function use a replace strategy to sample from the given interval. Why we need a decreasing probability, I've seen a similar algorithm without decrease the replacement probability. What is the difference. The code is as:

```
/*This is an excerpt from STL implementation*/
template <class InputIterator, class RandomAccessIterator, class Distance>
RandomAccessIterator __random_sample(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                                         RandomAccessIterator out,
                                 const Distance n)
{
  Distance m = 0;
  Distance t = n;
  for ( ; first != last && m < n; ++m, ++first) //the strategy is also used in mahout
    out[m] = *first;//fill it

    while (first != last) {
        ++t;
        Distance M = lrand48() % t;
        if (M < n)
          out[M] = *first;//replace it with a decreasing probability
        ++first;
    }

  return out + m;
}
```

Comment: Don't create global names with leading underscores, those are reserved.

Comment: And is the question what the difference is between your function is compared to the one in the standard library?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This is an excerpt of the implementation of STL, the version is sgi-2.9. And of course this is a internal used function, and is not part of the interfaces to the user. My question is why the strategy is used, basically I am wandering why the probability is decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that the first element (indeed, the first `n` elements) has to be chosen with the probability of `1` (the "fill it" stage). In order to remain in the final sample, this first element needs then to survive `m-n` possible replacements - that's what brings the probability of it being in the sample down to `n/m`. On the other hand, the last element only participates in one replacement; it should thus be added to the sample with the probability of `n/m` from the start.

For simplicity, suppose that you only need to pick one element, out of `m`, using this replacement strategy (note that you don't know up front what `m` is: you just iterate until you suddenly reach the end). You take the first element, and keep it with a probability of `1` (for all you know, this is the only element). Then you discover the second element, and you throw a coin and either keep it or discard it with the probability of `1/2`. At this point, each of the first two elements has `1/2` probability to be the chosen one.

Now you see the third element, and you keep it with probability of `1/3`. Each of the first two elements had `1/2` probability of participating in this encounter, and `2/3` of surviving it - for a total of `1/2 * 2/3 == 1/3` probability of still being around. So, again, each of the first three elements has `1/3` probability of being chosen at this point.

The inductive step of proving that, after `t`th element is inspected, each of the first `t` elements has `1/t` probability of being chosen is left as an exercise for the reader. So is the extension of the proof to a sample of size `n > 1`.